# Restkit simple NSDictionary mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Seems like a really easy task, but I find myself struggling..
I have this JSON response:

```
{"data":
    {"badParams":
        {"arbitraryKey":"arbitraryValue",
        "arbitraryKey2":"arbitraryValue2",
        "arbitraryKey3":"arbitraryValue3" ,
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to parse that response to NSDictionary, containing all the `key:value` pairs I got in the response:

```
NSDictionary *response == {"arbitraryKey":"arbitraryValue",
            "arbitraryKey2":"arbitraryValue2",
            "arbitraryKey3":"arbitraryValue3",...}
```

I tried RKDynamicMapping but couldn't make it :\

Any advise?

Comment: Use NSJSONSerialization, parse the string, do `response = jsonResult[@"data"][@"badParams"];` and you've got it.

Answer (score 5):

RestKit is not be prepared for NSDictionarys. But you could do a bit ugly workaround if it is necessary...

This class wraps a dictionary in a container class thats forwarding the KVC calls to the `setObject:forKey` of the dictionary.

```
@interface RestKitDictionaryContainer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * dictionary;
@end

@implementation RestKitDictionaryContainer

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [_dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}

-(id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [_dictionary objectForKey:key];
}
@end
```

Now you have to do all mappings as usual.
After a RestKit call you only have to get the dictionary out of this class or use it as a dictionary.
Well, I think this is pretty ugly and should not be used but it is your decision...

Comment: Really really very brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

If your target object is an NSDictionary, then you might be better suited to use [NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606842/654870) than RestKit. With RestKit you really don't parse JSON into dictionaries, but rather into native objective-c objects, i.e. your data models.

For more on setting up your own objects, relational mappings, and configuring the RestKit objectManager you should check out the [RestKit Object Mapping Guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping); they have some really solid examples on how that can be done.

UPDATE:

For a simple JSON -> NSDictionary mapping that does not require any authentication I would simply use this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourserver.com/api";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: So you're saying parsing to raw NSDictionary is not possible? This request is only a part of a full program, so Restkit is needed here (and not NSJSONSerialization).

Comment: @Rizon - What do you mean by "raw NSDictionary"??  The above does return an NSDictionary, and doing `parsedData[data"][@"badParams"]` will get you to the inner dictionary you want.

Comment: Great simple solution. Make sure to throw this on a background thread if you're going to use it in production.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize  @Xean 's solution, here is the working code snippet.

```
RKObjectMapping *dictionaryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RestKitDictionaryContainer class]];
[dictionaryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"arbitraryKey", @"arbitraryKey2", @"arbitraryKey3"]];
```

then create response descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dictionaryMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                        pathPattern:@"/your/api"
                                            keyPath:@"data.badParams"
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

finally the request operation part

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSString *value = [((RestKitDictionaryContainer *)[[mappingResult dictionary] objectForKey:@"content"]).dictionary objectForKey:@"arbitraryKey"];
            //....
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];
[objectRequestOperation start];
```