# How do i convert a json string with an array of objects to an nsarray with nsdictionaries - IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

i already found a way to convert a json string like {"a":"b"} to an nsdictionary in IOS. [How do i convert a JSON String to a dictionary in IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary-in-ios5)

But is there a way to convert something like that "[{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"}]" to an nsarray with nsdictionaries?

I need that for my API but still found no solution.

Hope someone can help me! Thanks

Jonny

Comment: Just a guess:  Use a JSON parser such as NSJSONSerialization.  (Or any of the other half-dozen JSON parsers for Objective-C listed at json.org.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly the same API. `-JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` will return an NSArray if the top-level item in your JSON is an array.

Comment: yes i just had to define my variable as an NSArray instead of NSDictionary... stupid...