# iOS7 is there a lightweight JSON to Object mapper, (NOT RestKit or NSJSONSerialization)?

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, gson, restkit

My current project uses AFNetworking 2.2 and in general refuses to compile when I add Restkit. **Is there a way for me to get some equivalent of RKObjectMapping as defined below from some other lightweight library?** I'm talking about taking JSON and turning it into a custom value object, not just a dictionary or array.

Google GSON for Android comes to mind, is there something like that for iOS?

What' I'm trying to accomplish:

```
static RKObjectMapping* mapping = nil;

+(RKObjectMapping*)objectMapping
{

    if(mapping != nil)
    {
        return mapping;
    }

    //allows automatic unpacking of JSON payloads into  Value Objects
    //https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping


    //JSON - VO
    mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyVO class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"label": @"label",
                                                         @"icon": @"iconName",
                                                         @"action": @"actionName",
                                                         @"children": @"children"
                                                         }];

    return mapping;

}
```

Comment: Use NSJSONSerialization to produce an NSDictionary, then write an `initWithDict:` method for your class.  Gives you complete control, and not really any more difficult than doing the "automatic" object mapping for anything beyond the most trivial case.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213707/parsing-json-to-a-predefined-class-in-objective-c/25213946#25213946

Comment: This is what I'm currently using, but was hoping there's something to make this simpler.

Comment: I have struggled a lot about this this is easiest way. a call matches with your json then just call it. if you want to extend the class at runtime you can add properties with matching new keys in your json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried NSJsonSerialization (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html)? It seems to accomplish what you need. I use it whenever I need to parse anything in JSON format,

Comment: The question clearly states NOT NSJsonSerialization.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken...and blind, the title was changed long after I posted this answer

Comment: In that case, I apologise. You took the effort to post an answer, and it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dict {
    id self = [super init];
    if (id) {
        self.label = dict[@"label"];
        self.icon = dict[@"iconName"];
        self.action = dict[@"actionName"];
        self.children = dict[@"children"];
    }
    return id;
}
```