# Can reusing the same NSError object be problematic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reference, nserror

I have since changed my implementation to *not* do this anymore, but I would be interested in knowing if the following could lead to issues - take for example a process that has multiple steps, each involving passing a reference to an NSError object. If you were to reuse this error object each step along the way, would that reference be negatively effected in some way, perhaps leading to some sort of memory management/dealloc crash?

## Example (most of the in-between code has been omitted)

```
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:&error];

    if (!data) {
        return error;
    }

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (!responseData) {
        return error;
    }

    NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

    if (!resultDictionary) {
        return error;
    }
```

Even though the error is never "used" twice, meaning the error will be nil (it seems) the next time its reference is passed to another method, could the reference be effected in some way at any of the steps along the way?

***Original code prior to editing in response to jlehr's comments:***

```
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:&error];

    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

    if (error) {
        return;
    }
```

EDIT: To anyone coming to this at a later date, the information jlehr is referring to can be found here:

> When dealing with errors passed by reference, it’s important to test
>   the return value of the method to see whether an error occurred, as
>   shown above. Don’t just test to see whether the error pointer was set
>   to point to an error.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, you should never check an `NSError` object returned by reference; instead, check the return value.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link to where that is in the docs? What do you mean by check the return value?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now what you mean by return value.. Brain fart..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation, you should never check an `NSError` object returned by reference. Instead, check the return value of the `init...` method or factory method you're calling, for example:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:&error];
if (data == nil) {
     // Handle failure. It's safe to use the error object here.
}
```

However, your code doesn't appear to be doing anything with the `NSError` instance, (e.g., logging, or displaying an alert), so you can just pass `NULL` instead.

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:NULL];
if (data == nil) {
     // Handle failure.
}
```

Comment: My code does actually quite a bit more, including logging, analytics, as well as returning the error as a parameter in a block, I just omitted that for this example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so other than this, my main question revolves around using the same error object repeatedly. If I pass a reference to it in to all of those methods, and they all work fine, but in the last method there's an error, could the error object have been effected by the repeated reference passing even if no error occurs?

Comment: You're not passing an error object -- you're passing the address of an uninitialized local variable, so the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I just noticed you edited your question. You shouldn't do that without annotating the changes you made; otherwise readers won't understand answers posted before you made the changes.

Comment: What about my question doesn't make sense? Perhaps I'm being dense, but it would seem that knowing if there's a chance that the memory at that address would be altered in some way if the same reference is repeatedly passed to different methods is at least a clear question, if not a 'good' one. Also, apologies on the edit, I'll fix it.

Comment: The variable is uninitialized. That means the value at that address is undefined, so changing the value isn't going to mean anything. You pass the address so that if an error occurs, the method you're calling can write the address of an object into the variable for you. Since there's no guarantee the method won't write garbage into the address if an error *doesn't* occur, Apple's docs say that it's unsafe to test the value of the error variable. Given that you can't use the variable safely until an error has occurred, it doesn't matter if you previously passed the address to another method.

Comment: Note though that writing code in a confusing way is more likely to lead to mistakes. If you feel the code would be clearer if it defined a different error variable for each call, then by all means do so.

Comment: I appreciate the responses - you've definitely helped understand what could potentially have been a problem here. One issue I've seen that I've never been able to reproduce locally has to do with NSError dealloc/release objc_msgSend, which I suspect might be related to what I've been doing.

Comment: One more quick question, is there a functional difference between NSError *error; and NSError *error = nil;?

Comment: No. Again, since you should never check an `NSError` returned by reference, the initialization is meaningless, and potentially misleading.