# How to parse a response obtained with AFNetworking 1.0 using JSON format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, afnetworking

I'm having a problem with `AFNetworking`.

Currently I can send a `POST` request in `JSON` format [`AFJSONParameterEncoding`] using `NSDictionary` to a server and it correctly replies, the problem is that the server replies with a `JSON` formatted response too, response I'm able to convert to `NSString` using:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// responseObject is the server response
```

The problem is I'm not able to transform the response in any other format, other than `NSString` like in the code posted before. How can that be possible? I would like to convert the response to JSON format so I can read a precise value, the value associated with the key `"isInformative"`

Here's my code so far:

```
NSDictionary *requestBody = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"value1", @"key1",
                                     @"value2", @"key2",
                                     nil];

NSDictionary *requestHead = @{
                              @"RequestHead": requestBody
                             };

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"/public-mobile-sdk/"
                                                  parameters:requestHead];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, id responseObject) {
    // Here I can convert the responseObject to NSSTring correctly
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[requestOperation start];
```

**Note** - I can't update the AFNetworking version bundled in the Xcode project since it's not my own, so sadly I must stick and use version 1.X

Comment: See this and many others:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-string-into-an-nsdictionary-for-ios-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:jailbreakRequest];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, id responseObject) {
    //Place this line of code below to create a NSDictionary from the async server response
    NSDictionary *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[requestOperation start];
```

Thanks anyway :-)