# How to extract encapsulated JSON from Firebase Cloud Message?

Tags: android, json, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send from Firebase Messages in this structure:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/myapp",
    "data": {
        "id" : "id123",
        "title" : "lksdjkrfrfrereflsjd",
        "body" : "fsdfsd",
        "de": {
            "key1" : "val1",
            "key2" : "val2"
         },
        "en": {
            "key3" : "val3",
            "key4" : "val4"
         }
     }
}
```

in my `override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?)` method my remoteMessage object has a data field which is from type: `Map<String, String>`

How can I access `de` and `en` from `remoteMessage` ?

EDIT: It is developed for Android

Comment: It counts now as a regular String value. You're going to have to parse it to JSON. I'm not too familiar with iOS yet, maybe try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8606444/4625829)