# How to convert String to dictionary iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

[{ 'langkey':'Arabic','value':'المملكة العربية السعودية'} ,{ 'langkey':'English','value':'Saudi Arabia'} ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deserialize a JSON string into an NSDictionary? (For iOS 5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-string-into-an-nsdictionary-for-ios-5)

Comment: thats not works for me. I am getting string from server like below.  [{ 'langkey':'Arabic','value':'المملكة العربية السعودية'} ,{ 'langkey':'English','value':'Saudi Arabia'} ]

Comment: Consider that the string is not valid JSON

Comment: Can you plz tell me how i can split ?

Comment: Replace the single quotes with double quotes and deserialize the string as described the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to create a valid JSON first:

```c
NSString *validJsonString = [@"[{ 'langkey':'Arabic','value':'المملكة العربية السعودية'} ,{ 'langkey':'English','value':'Saudi Arabia'} ]" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\""];
```

Then, do this:

[How do I deserialize a JSON string into an NSDictionary? (For iOS 5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-string-into-an-nsdictionary-for-ios-5)